# nm-applet icon disappears after connecting in tint2 panel

Tags: panel, openbox, network-manager

I am using `openbox` and my panel of choice is `tint2`. Everything is working fine with tint2 except `nm-applet`.

Problem I am facing is nm-applet icon shows fine when I am not connected to any network but as soon as I get connected to a network it `disappears`. nm-applet is working because I can still access all its option by right-clicking on it but the icon is invisible.

**Before connecting :**

[image]

**After connection:**

[image]

[tint2 config file](http://sprunge.us/EIeb)

So as you can see in the above two images the icon disappears after the connection is established.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: @izx: ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your icon-theme. Or alter the size of the panel/systray icon size and see if that works. Maybe your theme can't find the right icon and draws a blank (`systray_icon_size = xx`)